# Scraping data from site with more button and JSON file doesn't load

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, screen-scraping

So I am trying to scrape all the available jobs from the following site: `https://apply.workable.com/fitxr/` The issue is that the site uses javascript and has a load more button.

I went to the chrome network settings and found the json file that the site uses
[image: chrome network]

however when I go to the site `https://apply.workable.com/api/v3/accounts/fitxr/jobs` I get an not found error [image: site error]

Not sure how to get the data.

here is the code I wrote to try and scrape the data via xpath.

```
    data = []
    headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
    }
    url = "https://apply.workable.com/fitxr/"
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    xpath = '/html/body/div/div/div/main/div[2]/ul/li[*]/div/h3'
    jobs = tree.xpath(xpath)
    for job in jobs:
        print(job.text)
```

and here using the JSON site

```
    data = []
    url = "https://apply.workable.com/api/v3/accounts/fitxr/jobs"
    r = requests.get(url)
    json = r.json()
    for x in range(len(json["results"])):
        print(json["results"][x]["title"])
```

both sets of code return nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you found in your browser's development tools is a `POST` request to the `/jobs` endpoint; your attempt used `requests.get` (which sends a `GET` request to the same endpoint). `/jobs` does not respond to `GET` reqests, apparently.

Change your call to `requests.get()` to `requests.post()`, instead:

```
import requests 

data = []
url = "https://apply.workable.com/api/v3/accounts/fitxr/jobs"
r = requests.post(url)
json = r.json()
for x in range(len(json["results"])):
    print(json["results"][x]["title"])
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://replit.com/@esqew/UnusedUnlawfulGreenware#main.py)

Results:

```
Engineering Manager - Services & Full Stack
Interim Talent Partner
Customer Experience Manager
Content Manager (Production)
Performance Marketing Manager
Performance Marketing Manager
Content Creator (Fitness and Music)
Content Creator (Fitness and Music)
Automation Tester
Engineering Manager - Security, Data and DevOps
```